# How does ASP.Net Web API validate OAuth 2.0 token?

Tags: asp.net, .net, oauth-2.0, asp.net-web-api

I'm creating a test project with our IDP server. We have created a simple Web API sample project which return the claims of the users on its get method. We have also created the token by using OAuth Flow **GrantResourceOwnerCredentials** or Flow 3 in specs. Few things i didn't quite understand, need some help to get some more understanding :-

- How does the Web API knows that token is coming from authorized
  client and how does it get validated.
- Where in Web Api code, we can override and check the OAuth incoming token and its validation. In production environment, we will have separate HA server for IDP and Web API, so do we need to specify some certificate in web config?
- Can we have all the Auth mechanism available to the Web Api? like basic , OAuth etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> How does the Web API knows that token is coming from authorized client and how does it get validated.

Normally access token is passed through HTTP Headers like Authorization. You can use handlers in web api on specific routes and check this token with your logic

> Where in Web Api code, we can override and check the OAuth incoming
>   token and its validation. In production environment, we will have
>   separate HA server for IDP and Web API, so do we need to specify some
>   certificate in web config?

As said above. Best place is handler

```
public class AuthenticationHandler : DelegatingHandler
{
    protected override Task<HttpResponseMessage> SendAsync(HttpRequestMessage request, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        //...
    }
 }
```

and don't forget to configure to use your authentication handler for some specific routes

```
public static void Register(HttpConfiguration config)
{
   // ...
   config.MessageHandlers.Add(new AuthenticationHandler());
   // ...
}
```

You need certificate only if your logic needs this certificate to validate your token. The best way is to store and read it to/from windows certificate storage and configure in web.config only thumbprint of certificate you need, so no user names, or plain text password in web.config.

> Can we have all the Auth mechanism available to the Web Api? like
>   basic , OAuth etc.

Yes, you can use basic authentcation together with OAuth, just use something to differentiate, like different HTTP Headers suitable for autorization, but it's not clear for me, why you need to support e.g. basic together with oauth, maybe it will have more sense to use only easier one - basic.

Most of information you need is gathered here http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/security

Comment: Nice explanation. I don't want to use machine keys to create token as OWIN framework use this by default. Is there any other way around to use certificates. I have two Resource server, is it possible to send same token to both app so both can use their certificate to validate the token :}